# If I am reading an input by STDIN in Ruby. How do I put it in a hashtable?

Tags: ruby, hash

If I get an input,

> Tom 176
>
> Joe 170

How do I put in a hashtable where

> {:name => "Tom", :height => 176}
>
> {:name => "Joe", :height => 170}

Comment: you say "hashtable" but you show an array, what do you really need?

Answer (score 4):

The output you quote is an array of hashes, with each hash just having two keys. Is that really what you want? If so, it's done like this:

```
array = []
while line = gets do
    name, height = line.split
    array << { :name => name, :height => height.to_i }
end
```

If you instead want a hash with the name as keys and the height as values, it'd look like this:

```
hash = {}
while line = gets do
    name, height = line.split
    hash[name] = height.to_i
end
```

Comment: Thanks! The second one looks fine.

Comment: As the input is received by standard input. How does the program understand which one is name and which one is the height?
Does the line:
name, height = line.split
understand the difference?

Comment: `line.split` means: take the string `line` and divide it into parts, separated by whitespace. So `"Tom 176".split` give you an array `["Tom", "176"]`. You can assign an array to multiple variable. If you have `array = ["Tom", "176"]` then `name, height = array` is the same as `name = array[0]; height = array[1]`

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

If you want a hash *{name => height}*, use [Hash::[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D):

```
Hash[open("filename.txt").lines.map do |line| 
  name, height = line.split
  [name, height.to_i]
end]
#=> {"Joe"=>170, "Tom"=>176}
```

If you want an array of hashes:

```
open("filename.txt").lines.map do |line| 
  name, height = line.split
  {:name => name, :height => height.to_i}
end
#=> [{:name => "Tom", :height => 176}, {:name => "Joe", :height => 170}]
```